# What's new in Gnome Panel 3.2?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, customization, applet

Gnome Panel, also known as Ubuntu/Gnome Classic, is available in a brand new version for Gnome 3. One of the things I like about it, is that when you use vertical panels, applets are made vertical as well, including text. This is something I've longed for for many years. That's one of the benefits of GTK3.

Another change is that you now have to press alt+middleclick to move stuff around. That's also nice, though it does take some getting used to.

This got me thinking that there might be other things that aren't so easily discovered. So I thought I'd ask the experts! What other things are new, and what can we expect in the near future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a list of changes by reading the commit messages for gnome-panel on GNOME's git log.
http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-panel/log/